# Custom Audio Player play and pause button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, audio-streaming

I am creating an audio playlist. I have created the custom audio player using the code below. It works fine although the issue is that i have auto play on which means that when the first song is over it automatically goes into the next song. This causes the play pause button to be all messed up. It is kind of hard to explain though if you go to [this link](https://tunechestmusic.000webhostapp.com/) and go the very end of a song you will know what i mean. Please help me, this is really holding me back.

```
        <!--HTML5 audio-->
<audio id="audioPlayer" preload="true">
    <source src="oh-my.mp3">      
</audio>

<div id="wrapper">
    <!--Audio Player Interface-->
    <div id="audioplayer">
        <button id="pButton" class="play"></button>
        <div id="timeline">
            <div id="playhead"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/html5audio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: That link is to a web site the has a bad security certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend listening to the `onplay` event in your JavaScript. This event is raised when the audio starts playing. Here's an example:

```
document.getElementById('audioPlayer').onplay = function(){
    document.getElementById('pButton').style.background = "url(pause.png)"
}
```

This causes the button to be changed to a pause button whenever the audio plays, regardless of whether is was started by a user click. I hope this helps!

***EDIT***

I've looked at your code some more, and I've discovered that this works:

```
$("#audioPlayer").on("ended play", function(){
    $("#pButton").addClass("pause").removeClass("play")
})
```

Comment: Thank you but where would i put that line of code in my java script.

Comment: It's really up to you :) This block of code could go anywhere. You might need to add another block that handles the `onpause` event.

Comment: This is the code i have though know the image wont even show up. 
 `document.getElementById('audioPlayer').onplay = function(){
    document.getElementById('pButton').style.background = "url(../img/pause.png)"
}
document.getElementById('audioPlayer').onpause = function(){
    document.getElementById('pButton').style.background = "url(../img/play.png)"
}
`

Comment: @TuneChest000, see the edit above. I've spent some time looking at your code, and this will work better. You can add it at the bottom of the `<script>` you already have. Let me know if this works!

Comment: It worked thank you so much although now when i click on a song i am getting the issue i had with the song ending. Any ideas for how to fix this. Either that or a way to have the default button as II because i have it set so that when the page is refreshed the audio starts playing

Comment: OK, I've updated the code above to the following:

`$("#audioPlayer").on("ended play", function(){
    $("#pButton").addClass("pause").removeClass("play")
})`

Adding the `play` event fixes your issue. I hope this works!

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help ;) Don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: How do i accept the answer, also one last question i promise. How do i make the clickable area for the progress bar larger without actually increasing the size of the progress bar just to make it more touch friendly.

Comment: To accept my answer, just click the grey checkbox below the voting arrows.

As for making the click area larger, you'll have to open another Stack Overflow question. ;) That opens it up to other potential answerers.